# Logisitic Regression Cost Function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)
m = length(y);
h = sigmoid(X*theta);
sh = sigmoid(h);
grad = (1/m)*X'*(sh - y);
J = (1/m)*sum(-y.*log(sh) - (1 - y).*log(1 - sh));

end
```

I'm trying to compute the cost function for logistic regression. Can someone please tell me why this isn't accurate?

[image]

Update: Sigmoid function

```
function g = sigmoid(z)

g = zeros(size(z));
g = 1./(1 + exp(1).^(-z));

end
```

Comment: I just took a look at this, and it seems to be right... Could it be a problem of `sigmoid` function? And is it correct, that you use it twice (for `X*theta` and then one more time for `h`)?
By the way, How you get that it is not accurate?

Comment: I posted the sigmoid function. As far as I can tell it's working properly.

Comment: What's your variable `m` ?. You reference it in the `costFunction` but don't pass it in.

Comment: You can rewrite your sigmoid function as `1./(1+exp(-z))` btw and leave off the `zeros` there. Otherwise, I would think your issue is that you are calling `sigmoid` twice...

Comment: Thanks Justin and Dan. I forgot to add m to my question and just added it. It was in my code already. Dan, I don't understand how calling sigmoid twice is an issue. How would you suggest I fix it?

Comment: @TylerLangan why are you calling it twice? you're basically saying that your h(x) equals `sigmoid(sigmoid(X*theta))`, when it should just be `sigmoid(X*theta)`. try replacing all your `sh` in your calculation of `J` with `h`

Comment: Thank you Dan, Mikhail, and Justin for your contributions. Takeshi helped elaborate on what Dan was saying. Having an account with a positive reputation where I can ask questions is really important to me and my career. Is there a way I can improve this question so it doesn't have negative reputation?

Comment: @TylerLangan I don't know why you were downvoted, but I would suggest that you include a description of what doesn't work or how you know that it doesn't work in future. So usually that would mean either showing how your output differs from the desired output or showing which line had an error and posting the exact error message. In this case you probably should have elaborated on your test rig, how did you come to the conclusion that this wasn't accurate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Dan stated, your costFunction calls sigmoid twice. First, it performs the sigmoid function on `X*theta`; then it performs the sigmoid function again on the result of `sigmoid(X*theta)`. Thus, `sh = sigmoid(sigmoid(X*theta))`. Your cost function should only call the sigmoid function once.

See the code below, I removed the `sh` variable and replaced it with `h` everywhere else. This causes the sigmoid function to only be called once.

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)
m = length(y);
h = sigmoid(X*theta);
grad = (1/m)*X'*(h - y);
J = (1/m)*sum(-y.*log(h) - (1 - y).*log(1 - h));

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Having an account in good standing is really important to me. Is there a way I can improve this question so it doesn't have a down vote?

Comment: People may have downvoted your question since it seems to stem from a homework problem. As a new user myself, my advice for you to raise your reputation is to answer some questions, rather than trying to improve the score of this post :)

Comment: Nice job. I originally didn't see the duplicate sigmoid call.